# Ошибка NoSuchMethodError при выполнении программы

Tags: java

Есть два класса, первый класс создает экземпляр второго класса. Выглядит это так, первый класс:

```
Inv inv;
String[] tLine = line.split(";");
inv = new Inv();
inv.setDebet(tLine[7]);
inv.setCredit(tLine[10]);
```

Собственно второй класс до противного прост:

```
public class Inv {
    String mDebet;
    String mCredit;
    String mOperator;
    String mReestr;
    String mDate;
    String mCur;
    int mSumma;
    String mPurpose;

    public Inv() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getDebet() {
        return mDebet;
    }

    public void setDebet(String debet) {
        mDebet = debet;
    }

    public String getCredit() {
        return mCredit;
    }

    public void setCredit(String credit) {
        mCredit = credit;
    }
}
```

Компилируется без проблем, а вот при выполнении ругается NoSuchMethodError.
Собственно что я делаю не так?

Comment: Это весь код? В какой конкретно строке происходит исключение?

Comment: вот в этой строчки - inv.setDebet(tLine[7]); - если ее закоментарить то в следующий. если убрать tLine и вставить просто строчку ровно такая же ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя ошибка. Не увидел что во внешней библиотеки есть класс Inv.